# Facebook payments : invalid og type. Expected og:product, got website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I try to implement facebook payments , but i have problem implement it , i am new to this can anybody help me for this issue ,

My html meta has the following

```
<head prefix=
"og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
<meta property="og:type"                   content="product" />
<meta property="og:title"                  content="{{ $records['title']}}" />
<meta property="og:image"                  content="{{ $records['image']}}" />
<meta property="og:description"            content="testing description" />
<meta property="og:url"                    content="{{ $records['image']}}" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My Sample Payment App</title>
```

and i have a app id , for security purpose i am not include here, the script has the following,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myappid',// i give it in my code.
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });

    function buy() {
      var obj = {
        method: 'pay',
        action: 'purchaseitem',
        product: "{{ $records['image']}}"
      };

      FB.ui(obj, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    }

    document.getElementById('pay').onclick = function() {buy()};
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
```

I got this error

```
Object {error_code: 1383146, error_message: "invalid og type. Expected og:product, got website"}
```

Comment: Its an very very urgent issue , can anybody help me quickly .. thanks a lot and lot in advance

Comment: The `product` must be the HTML page for that product, not the image. Images don’t have meta tags.